# "Er ist gut darin" für "He is good at it"?

Tags: usage, preposition

Aus [diesem Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/gut):

> Er ist in Spanisch sehr gut.

Kann man dann das Folgende sagen?

> Er hat Spanisch in der Schule gelernt, aber **darin** ist er nicht ganz gut.

Klingt "darin" hier etwas komisch, oder ist es doch in Ordnung?

Comment: Das ist genau richtig, nur „nicht ganz gut“ ist etwas daneben. Vielleicht „nicht so gut“, „nicht besonders gut“.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das ist völlig ok so.

Wenn man die Betonung auf die Qualität seiner Fähigkeit (bzw. des Fehlens dieser) legen will, kann man auch sagen:

> Er hat Spanisch in der Schule gelernt, aber gut ist er nicht darin.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde "gut in xyz" hauptsächlich für Schulfächer verwenden, z. B. "Er ist gut in Mathe." aber nicht für andere Fähigkeiten wie "Er ist gut im Gitarrespielen".

Stattdessen würde ich sagen "er spielt gut Gitarre" oder "er kennt sich mit Geografie gut aus" oder, in Deinem Beispiel, "Er hat Spanisch in der Schule gelernt, aber sein Spanisch ist nicht besonders gut".

Answer (score 1):

Man kann natürlich vieles sagen. Ich würde es vermutlich so formulieren:

> Er hat Spanisch in der Schule gelernt, aber er kann es nicht gut.